# php приходит response null

Tags: javascript, php

Есть такая проблема с которой не могу разобратся.
Пример сделал для теста.
У меня есть

```
    <input type="text" />
    <button>Введите Имя</button>

JS

    let button = document.querySelector("button");
    let input = document.querySelector("input");
    
    button.addEventListener("click", () => {
      axios
        .post("./api/post.php", {
          name: input.value,
        })
        .then(function (response) {
          console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
    });
PHP
<?php
echo $_POST['name'];
?>
Я делаю запрос к файлу php

Код взят с примера. И я в ответ должен получить Andrey
Но response у меня NULL
**Подскажите что не так. Делал запрос через postMan все работает как надо response приходит Andrey**
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А разные ссылки на скрине и в скрипте это норма?

Comment: Если я не ошибаюсь, то вы отправляете json, а php не парсит автоматически json в post body. Отправьте данные в виде application form data и тогда всё будет

Comment: Огромное спасибо. Вы направили меня

Answer (score 0):

Нашел ответ 
Cпасибо  ArchDemon за ваш коменьарий который меня направил.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44799589/php-post-array-empty-on-axios-post

Answer (score 0):

Вот решение данной проблемы

```
$_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
```